# The script is installed in directory, which is not PATH

Tags: windows, python, pip

During the installation process of Jupiter Notebook using pip, it said that scripts were installed in a folder that is not on PATH. Can it cause any problems? How can I fix it?

Here is full log:

```
Installing collected packages: six, ipython-genutils, decorator, traitlets, jupyter-core, jsonschema, nbformat, tornado, pyzmq, entrypoints, pygments, MarkupSafe, jinja2, webencodings, bleach, mistune, pandocfilters, testpath, defusedxml, nbconvert, Send2Trash, wcwidth, prompt-toolkit, parso, jedi, colorama, pickleshare, backcall, ipython, python-dateutil, jupyter-client, ipykernel, pywinpty, terminado, prometheus-client, notebook
  The scripts jupyter-migrate.exe, jupyter-troubleshoot.exe and jupyter.exe are installed in 'c:\users\рубена\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The script jsonschema.exe is installed in 'c:\users\рубена\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The script jupyter-trust.exe is installed in 'c:\users\рубена\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The script pygmentize.exe is installed in 'c:\users\рубена\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  Running setup.py install for MarkupSafe ... done
  Running setup.py install for pandocfilters ... done
  The script jupyter-nbconvert.exe is installed in 'c:\users\рубена\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  Running setup.py install for backcall ... done
  The scripts iptest.exe, iptest3.exe, ipython.exe and ipython3.exe are installed in 'c:\users\рубена\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The scripts jupyter-kernel.exe, jupyter-kernelspec.exe and jupyter-run.exe are installed in 'c:\users\рубена\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  Running setup.py install for pywinpty ... done
  Running setup.py install for prometheus-client ... done
  The scripts jupyter-bundlerextension.exe, jupyter-nbextension.exe, jupyter-notebook.exe and jupyter-serverextension.exe are installed in 'c:\users\рубена\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed MarkupSafe-1.0 Send2Trash-1.5.0 backcall-0.1.0 bleach-3.0.2 colorama-0.4.0 decorator-4.3.0 defusedxml-0.5.0 entrypoints-0.2.3 ipykernel-5.1.0 ipython-7.1.1 ipython-genutils-0.2.0 jedi-0.13.1 jinja2-2.10 jsonschema-2.6.0 jupyter-client-5.2.3 jupyter-core-4.4.0 mistune-0.8.4 nbconvert-5.4.0 nbformat-4.4.0 notebook-5.7.0 pandocfilters-1.4.2 parso-0.3.1 pickleshare-0.7.5 prometheus-client-0.4.2 prompt-toolkit-2.0.7 pygments-2.2.0 python-dateutil-2.7.5 pywinpty-0.5.4 pyzmq-17.1.2 six-1.11.0 terminado-0.8.1 testpath-0.4.2 tornado-5.1.1 traitlets-4.3.2 wcwidth-0.1.7 webencodings-0.5.1
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer to how can you fix it is in the very log you've posted.

Add the location

```
c:\users\рубена\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Scripts
```

to the Python path directory.

Rather than replicate instructions, you can follow this answer: [Add Directory to Python Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath)

---

Will this cause any problems?

If you attempt to access that script without specifying the exact location, Python won't be able to find it. Only you'll know if that actually causes an issue for you.

Comment: Is there a way to have `pip3` add the directory to the PATH?

Comment: What about installing to a directory expected by python, so it doesn't have this problem? Is this the directory expected by python?

Answer (score 13):

For Windows, follow these steps:

1. Go to File Explorer. 
   Navigate to C: → Users → (your user name) → AppData → Local → Programs → Python → Python38-32 (your python version) → Scripts
2. Copy this path,
   e.g.,
      `C:\Users\(your username)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts`
3. Right click on the "Computer", "My Computer" or "This PC" icon → select "Properties". 
   Click on "Advanced system settings" (on the left side). 
   (Enter your administrator password when requested.) 
   In the "System Properties" window, click on "Environment Variables" (near the bottom). 
   In the "Environment Variables" window,
   search for `PATH` under "System Variables". 
   Select it and click on "Edit…". 
   Add a semicolon (";") to the variable value
   and paste the path you had copied in step 1.
4. Close your Command Prompt window. 
   Open a new Command Prompt window.

You will now be able to run the commands you wanted to run.

Comment: I have not this path
`python --list-paths
unknown option --list-paths
usage: C:\Users\aleks\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
Try `python -h' for more information.`
and here no `Scripts` file

Comment: you can simplify a part of this by using `%USERPROFILE%`, e.g. `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts`

Answer (score 8):

*For me, the solution posted by Stese didn't work and wasn't helpful at all, thus I am posting it to update the thread and help the community.*

### For those using MAC-OS

---

#### Solution 1:

Despite I had configured properly the `$PYTHONPATH`, the terminal still wasn't able to find the package installed.

So instead I opened the `~/.bashrc` (or `~/.zshrc` if you are using the new `zsh`, available for mac-os Catalina 10.15.x or newer) and pasted the following:

```bsh
export PATH="${PATH}:/Users/caio.hc.oliveira/Library/Python/3.7/bin"
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/Users/caio.hc.oliveira/Library/Python/3.7/bin"
```

*saved the file and restarted the terminal.*

**IMPORTANT:** This is an example configured to my python's path. Find yours and substitute.

---

#### Solution 2:

If it is still not able to find the package, there is another possibility which is posting the `alias` pointing to the executable.

So in the same file `~/.bashrc` (or if your using `zsh` it would be `~/.zshrc`), you can just append at the end :

```bsh
alias jupyter='/Users/caio.hc.oliveira/Library/Python/3.7/bin/jupyter'
```

*Save it and restart the terminal.*

**IMPORTANT:** This is an example configured to my python's path. Find yours and substitute.

you can use it to point at any executable ;)

Comment: shouldn't we use `~/.bash_profile` on macOS?

Comment: Your Solution 1 works like a charm form me, the other solutions didn't work. Thanks a lot for this post.