# Adding pip, pip3, pip3.7 to PATH

Tags: python, python3, pip

Hi after the installation, I got this warning:

```
The scripts pip, pip3 and pip3.7 are installed in '/Users/stevetsang/Library/Python/3.7/bin' which is not on PATH. Consider adding this directory to PATH
```

Does this matter? If yes, could someone tells me on what command to move the scripts to PATH? Thank you

**OS: MacOs**

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/1538940/855367